# SQLite error when parseInt

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to using SQLite. Since this is my first time try to implement the SQLite, so I follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

But I got an error like this

```
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): Process: com.indomultimedia.hellobali, PID: 1710
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.indomultimedia.hellobali/com.indomultimedia.hellobali.MainHelloballi}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:354)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at com.indomultimedia.hellobali.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:98)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at com.indomultimedia.hellobali.MainHelloballi.onCreate(MainHelloballi.java:177)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
08-21 20:47:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     ... 11 more
```

Here's the error line on my code.

**MainHellobali.java**

```
    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
    List<AllItem> allItem = db.getAllContacts(); //Error in this line       

    for (AllItem cn : allItem) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.getTableID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getCategory_name() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getItem_name();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
// Getting All Contacts
public List<AllItem> getAllContacts() {
    List<AllItem> contactList = new ArrayList<AllItem>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALLITEM;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AllItem allitem = new AllItem();
            allitem.setTableID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))); // error in this line
            allitem.setCategory_name(cursor.getString(1));
            allitem.setItem_Name(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(allitem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

I have no idea why the error shows. I try to follow the tutorial as good as I can.
Anyone can help to fix this error?

Comment: The error message says it all. You are trying to parse a "null" database field to an `int`. p.s. You should call `cursor.getInt(0)` instead of `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))`.

Comment: In all database's, if the datatype is `integer` then must be fill Positive and negative counting numbers, as well as zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))` this is the line that triggers the error.

`cursor.getString(0)` returns `null`. Overall I would recommend you to substitute this line with the following: `cursor.getInt(0)`. This, however, will still be throwing if the column is null, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.